# How to config Ctrl+u to send signal SIGUSR1 from console

Tags: signals

I know stty support some defined key-stroke to send signals:

> $ stty -a | grep intr 
>  
>   intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;

Is it possible to configure [stty](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_stty.htm) to bind key-stroke "Ctrl+u" to send signal [SIGUSR1](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/programming/linux_pgsignals.html)? (Or any possible way)

Thanks in advance!

Ps. I want to use "Ctrl+u" to send signal to my foreground running program.

Comment: So far, I open a terminal and use command "kill -s USR1 myappid" to complete the request...

Comment: I found a negative answer... Orz: http://superuser.com/questions/310327/fedora-linux-way-to-use-stty-or-equivalent-to-bind-key-to-raise-sigusr1-for-a

Answer (score 1):

If you are in KDE and use Konsole for your application, you can send a USR1 signal to the application.

Open Edit in the menu and choose 'Send a signal', another window lets you choose the type of signal.

You can also, in Configuration, Shortcut, assign a key to SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2, etc...